# Setting color for the selected option in select angularjs

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have the following piece of code

```
<select class="mx-1" style="padding: 5px 0 5px 5px;"
     ng-model="vm.fruitName"
     ng-style="vm.addStyle"
     ng-change="vm.onFruitChange()"
     ng-click="vm.onFruitSelectClicked()"
     ng-options="fruit for fruit in vm.fruitNames">
     <option value="">---Select Fruit---</option>
</select>
```

and my controller code is

```
function onFruitChange() {
        vm.addStyle = {'color':vm.fruitColors[vm.fruitName]};
    }
    function onFruitSelectClicked() {
        vm.addStyle={};
    }
```

Now the problem is when user click on select and doesn't select any element, the previous element remains selected and i lost all the styling. Is there any way to handle this ?

Comment: Why you need to reset style on click? I mean why is there in the first place?

Comment: Because when i tried to change color then it shows all the values are of same color and it is little bit confusing to the user. that's why i am resetting it first.

Comment: Where do use `addStyle`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I corrected it now.

Comment: `and i lost all the styling` you lose only the `color`, right? Maybe it will be easier for me to understand if you create a **working** example (using snippet, jsbin etc.)

Comment: @MoshFeu Thanks I found the problem while i was writing jsbin example. Guess it was just a CSS property that needed to be apply. option:not(:checked) { color: black; }